# add calculated over groups columns to data frame preserving the initial order of rows

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, apply

Python 3.8.5, Pandas 1.1.4

```
test_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'key': ['a', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'a'],
    'id': [859, 849, 238, 977, 427, 760, 453, 664, 102, 128],
    'order': [92, 32, 60, 4, 18, 19, 43, 69, 14, 88],
    'value': [18, 12, 16, 77, 62, 93, 86, 14, 49, 89]
})

test_df

    key id      order   value
0   a   859     92      18
1   c   849     32      12
2   a   238     60      16
3   b   977     4       77
4   c   427     18      62
5   b   760     19      93
6   b   453     43      86
7   a   664     69      14
8   c   102     14      49
9   a   128     88      89
```

I need to calculate some characteristics for each row in key group with respect to order column, keep original order of rows and add calculated characteristics to the original data frame.

my approach is the following:

```
def add_columns(r, d):
    new_r = r.copy()
    new_r['total'] = d.query('order < @r.order')['value'].sum()
    new_r['check'] = any(r.value > d.query('order < @r.order')['value'])
    return new_r

test_df.groupby('key').apply(lambda df: df.apply(lambda row: add_columns(row, df), axis=1))

    key id  order   value   total   check
0   a   859 92      18      119     True
1   c   849 32      12      111     False
2   a   238 60      16      0       False
3   b   977 4       77      0       False
4   c   427 18      62      49      True
5   b   760 19      93      77      True
6   b   453 43      86      170     True
7   a   664 69      14      16      False
8   c   102 14      49      0       False
9   a   128 88      89      30      True
```

Is there more cleaner python-native or pandas-native approach? My code looks confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try self merge and query, then you can groupby:

```
df.join(df.reset_index().merge(df, on='key')
   .query('order_x > order_y')    # x will play role of `r` and `y` of `d` in your code
   .assign(check=lambda x: x['value_x']>x['value_y'])
   .groupby('index')
   .agg(total=('value_y','sum'), check=('check','any'))
   .reindex(df.index, fill_value=0)
)
```

Output:

```
  key   id  order  value  total  check
0   a  859     92     18    119   True
1   c  849     32     12    111  False
2   a  238     60     16      0      0
3   b  977      4     77      0      0
4   c  427     18     62     49   True
5   b  760     19     93     77   True
6   b  453     43     86    170   True
7   a  664     69     14     16  False
8   c  102     14     49      0      0
9   a  128     88     89     30   True
```

Answer (score 1):

Another version:

```
g = test_df.groupby("key")

test_df["total"] = g["order"].transform(
    lambda x: [test_df.loc[x[x < v].index, "value"].sum() for v in x]
)
test_df["check"] = g["order"].transform(
    lambda x: [
        (test_df.loc[i, "value"] > test_df.loc[x[x < v].index, "value"]).any()
        for i, v in zip(x.index, x)
    ]
)
print(test_df)
```

Prints:

```
  key   id  order  value  total  check
0   a  859     92     18    119   True
1   c  849     32     12    111  False
2   a  238     60     16      0  False
3   b  977      4     77      0  False
4   c  427     18     62     49   True
5   b  760     19     93     77   True
6   b  453     43     86    170   True
7   a  664     69     14     16  False
8   c  102     14     49      0  False
9   a  128     88     89     30   True
```